# www-data has access to my home directory files and folders

Tags: permissions

I've never noticed this before and I have no idea how this has happened but some files and directories in my home directory belong to the `www-data` group. Here is what I have.

```
drwx------  2 root www-data 4096 Jul 20 22:06 Mail
drwx------ 10 root www-data 4096 Aug 10 15:21 Maildir
drwxr-xr-x  2 root www-data 4096 Sep 15 23:57 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root www-data    0 Jul 18 22:21 oot
drwxrwxrwx  2 root www-data 4096 Oct  4 16:05 s
```

What should I do and should I be worried?

Answer (score 0):

We can't know how that happened. You haven't even told us if this is your personal computer, if it's a server, if it is your computer but acting as a server, what OS you are running or anything else that we might use to guess how it happened. You didn't even tell us where these files are found but, presumably, they are in directly under your `$HOME`.

Anyway, the first thing to do is find if this is a general thing or not (assuming a Linux machine):

```
find ~/ -group www-data
```

That will show a list of files and directories owned by the `www-data` group. To set them to be owned by you and your group instead, do (change `mk_89` to your actual user name):

```
find ~/ -group www-data -exec sudo chown mk_89:mk_89 {} +
```